# How do I create a rectangular array of arrays c#

Tags: c#

I want to create a 2D array (essentially a grid) such that each element is an integer array of length 2 (each element represents a 2D vector).

I intuitively thought that this would work but I get `invalid rank specifier`:

```
int[][,] rarr = new int[2][100, 100];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you're looking for is this:

```
int[][,] rarr = new int[2][,];
rarr[0] = new int[100, 100];
rarr[1] = new int[100, 100];
```

Or, more generally, this:

```
int[][,] rarr = new int[2][,];

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    rarr[i] = new int[100, 100];
```

Your code is attempting to allocate 3 distinct arrays in the one line of code - which you can't do. It's like you're trying to do the same as this illegal bit of code:

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> x = new List<new Dictionary<string, string>()>();
```

I feel like, from your description, you really actually want this:

```
int[,][] rarr = new int[100,100][];

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
        rarr[i, j] = new int[2];
```

Comment: Yes, I am after your final solution as it creates a `100*100` array where `i*j` is an int array of length 2. Is there no way to do this during declaration and initialisation?

Comment: @HarryStuart - No, if there were I would have put it in my answer. Do you appreciate why there can't be a way to do it?

Comment: Not really, I have previously created a dictionary of dictionaries and I thought I'd be able to create a multidimensional array of arrays also during initialisation.

Comment: @HarryStuart - You can't create a dictionary of dictionaries and initialize the inner dictionaries at the same time. The same applies with arrays.

Comment: Hmmm, my dictionary code is: `static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, JArray>> uploadDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, JArray>>();`. You're right. I'm initialising a dictionary of dictionaries, not initialising the dictionaries within the dictionary. Why does C# do forbid this?

Comment: @HarryStuart - Well in the case of `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, JArray>>` how can it know what keys will be used on the outer dictionary?